# why this $|r_{n}|=u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

let sequence $u_{n}>0$,and such
$$u_{n}\ge u_{n+1},n=1,2,\cdots,\lim_{n\to\infty}u_{n}=0$$
show that:
$$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}u_{n}-S_{n}|=u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots$$
where
$$S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}u_{i}$$

I know
$$r_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}u_{n}-S_{n}=\pm(u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots)$$
so my book say it's clearly
have
$$|r_{n}|=|\pm(u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots)|=u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots?$$
my question: why is clearly?

meaning clearly why
$$u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots>0?$$
Thank you  for you help

Comment: Look at each successive two terms in the series, they sum to a positive number.  Hence the result - the absolute value will be the sum of these positive numbers.

Comment: @Macavity,don't show this two case:$n=2k,n=2k+1?$

Comment: Don't need two cases.  $\vert\pm(u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}+\cdots)\rvert=\left| \left[u_{n+1}-u_{n+2}\right]+\left[u_{n+3}-u_{n+4}\right]+\cdots\right|$.  As $u_k \ge u_{k+1}$, the differences in the square brackets are non-negative, hence you can drop the absolute value.